# How to create interface in Vuejs like Angular when using with Laravel?

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, interface, vuejs2

I really do not sure when an object does not have interface.
It will make project hard to understand, when it does not have interface.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want use interfaces, use Typescript. You can find more info about this in docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html